# Android captive portal under Apache

Tags: android, apache, orange-pi

I am trying to set up a captive portal for mobile devices. I setted up dnmasq to resolve all DNS queries to hotspot IP. I configured Apache as:

```
RedirectMatch 302 /generate_204 http://jp.config/captive/login.html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/captive/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://jp.config/captive/login.html [L]
```

It works for one of my phones (Xiaomi), when I connect to hotspot a browser window opens automatically. I have another phone (Siemens J5) which doesn't work. When I connect to hotspot it says I may have no Internet access but no browser opens. I can see http://jp.config/captive/login.html gets called using tcpdump from server side but it never gets shown. That same Samsung mobile works ok using other captive portals.

Any additional config needed? Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Looking apache logs again it seems `/generate_204` does not generate a captive portal load, a second `/` call seems to produce a captive portal query. ???

```
"GET /generate_204 HTTP/1.1" 302 582 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.0; SM-J530F Build/NRD90M)"
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 575 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.0; SM-J530F Build/NRD90M)"
"GET /captive/login.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1448 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.0; SM-J530F Build/NRD90M)"
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 541 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.0; SM-J530F Build/NRD90M)"
"GET /generate_204 HTTP/1.1" 302 582 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.0; SM-J530F Build/NRD90M)"
```

Regards